# Saving a JSON value in relation to current user - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I need to accept Bitcoin and I am using Block.io API gem. In my payments controller I have a method that generates a new Bitcoin address from the API for the user to transfer bitcoins to. I need to know how to save this Bitcoin address in relation to the current user. I do have a User model and current_user is an instance of user.

The controller looks like this:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @new_address = BlockIo.get_new_address
   end
end
```

In the view when the user visits the Payments index page to make a payment, they get a new generated Bitcoin address.

In the view I access the JSON output to show the user the address like this:

```
<%= @address["data"]["address"] %>
```

And the JSON data that I receive looks like this:

```
{"status"=>"success", "data"=>{"network"=>"BTCTEST", "address"=>"2MstFNxtnp3pLLuXUK4Gra5dMcaz132d4dt", "available_balance"=>"0.01000000", "pending_received_balance"=>"0.00000000"}}
```

How can I save the bitcoin address from JSON to the database, specifically in relation to the current_user?

Any comment or answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any models?
You need to create a table on your database. This table will have a corresponding model in your rails app. Creating an entry is pretty straightforward.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: So you have a User model and current_user is an instance of user?  Can't you generate a bit_coin_address column?  `rails g AddBitCoinAddressToUser bit_coin_address:string` then `rake db:migrate` then in the index you can do `current_user.update_attribute(:bit_coin_address, BlockIo.get_new_address["data"]["address"])`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I would like to save multiple addresses should the user pay again. update_attribute would replace each the address each time.

Comment: Ok you can store an array... For database engines like Postgresql you can store arrays natively, for others you can use `serialize`. In either case you can then do `current_user.bit_coin_address << BlockIo.get ... ; current_user.save`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Thanks for your patience, I am getting a syntax error, can we simplify this and say there are no users, only a model called Payment with bitcoin:string. How can I save the bitcoin address in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, give it a shot: http://rubyjunky.com/rails-activerecord-serialize.html